# Player seems to be not rotating when applying rotation whereas floor seems to be rotating. How to reverse this case

Tags: three.js

[Camera view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L40x.jpg)

Camera settings:

```
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(32, aspectRatio(), 1, 1000)
camera.position.set(30, 30, 30)
```

I am adding camera to cube , cube.add(camera)
and then setting camera.lookAt(cube.position)

When i apply rotation.y to cube mesh in loop to keep cube rotating, it seems that cube is not rotating but floor is rotating.

I want cube to rotate as it rotates when Orbit control is used and Keeping the camera at same point with reference to cube.

If i remove lookAt(cube), cube rotates accordingly but camera don't follows cube properly when it is moving.

Comment: You might want to add your camera to the scene instead of adding it to the cube.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/question-about-third-person-like-camera-controls/9254